# Labeling a stacked bar plot (made with ggplot) after the y-range was altered

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since my stacked bar plot shows percentages and one variable is always 90%+, I altered the range of my plot in order to see the other variables better.
My problem now is, that after adding the labels, the labels of the one variable that is 90%+ is not beeing shown anymore (since it is outside of the viewed area).

The code:

```
ggplot(data=USB_Carbapenem_DDD_Perc_long, aes(x=Monat, y=DDDs, fill=`API`)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Relativer DDD-Verbrauch", labels = percent_format(accuracy=1)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(DDDs*100,"%")), position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3.5, label.padding=1) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.85, 1))
```

How it looks now:
[image]

My data (created via `dput`):

```
structure(list(API = c("ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", 
"meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", 
"rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", "rest", 
"ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", 
"imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", 
"meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", 
"rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", "rest", 
"ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", 
"imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", 
"meropenem", "rest", "ertapenem", "imipenem and cilstatin", "meropenem", 
"rest"), Monat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("Total", 
"Jan 2018", "Feb 2018", "Mär 2018", "Apr 2018", "Mai 2018", "Jun 2018", 
"Jul 2018", "Aug 2018", "Sep 2018", "Okt 2018", "Nov 2018", "Dez 2018"
), class = "factor"), DDDs = c(0.005, 0.006, 0.052, 0.937, 0.011, 
0.003, 0.05, 0.936, 0.01, 0.011, 0.056, 0.924, 0.006, 0.011, 
0.057, 0.925, 0.012, 0.006, 0.067, 0.915, 0.016, 0.016, 0.05, 
0.918, 0.013, 0.009, 0.063, 0.915, 0.019, 0.008, 0.07, 0.904, 
0.016, 0.011, 0.056, 0.918, 0.025, 0.008, 0.051, 0.915, 0.021, 
0.01, 0.048, 0.921, 0.02, 0.006, 0.066, 0.909)), row.names = 5:52, class = "data.frame")
```

As requested, a image of how I would like it to look:
[image]

I've tried to set `... position_stack(vjust=1), vjust=1, ...` in order to first put the numbers to the top and then lower it again a bit, but it looks really bad.
Is there a way to fix it? Maybe to put the labels in the middle of the viewed area?

Comment: Could you add sample data using `dput` rather than images? Also an image of what exactly you want it to look like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was not aware of `dput`, I'll add it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens that we can pass a `vjust` value for each of the `fill` levels, as in

```
position = position_stack(vjust = c(0.95, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
```

giving

[image]